# css on Rmarkdown: background for selected cells

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I use the `flextable` package to freeze the first row and the first column on an HTML report.
David Gohel recently added this option in `flextable` dev version (`0.8.3.13`) thanks to CSS comment.
However, I want to have the header cells with a white background.
I don't know the CSS language.
Anyone can help me having only the frozen header cells with a white background?

```
library(flextable)
dat <- lapply(1:30, function(x) rnorm(n = 50)) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("colname", 1:30)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

ft_1 <- flextable(dat)
ft_1 <- set_table_properties(ft_1, 
                             opts_html = list(
                               extra_css = ".tabwid tbody tr > :first-child {position: sticky;z-index: 1;left: 0;background: #ddd;}",
                               scroll = list(height="500px")))
ft_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the `.tabwid th {background-color: white; z-index: 2;}` in the `extra_css` argument of `set_table_properties`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

dat <- lapply(1:30, function(x) rnorm(n = 50)) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("colname", 1:30)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

ft_1 <- flextable(dat)
ft_1 <- set_table_properties(ft_1, 
                             opts_html = list(
                               extra_css = ".tabwid tbody tr > :first-child {position: sticky;z-index: 1;left: 0;background: #ddd;} .tabwid th {background-color: white; z-index: 2;}",
                               scroll = list(height="500px")))
ft_1
```
````